# Unable to add latitude and longitude points to folium map

Tags: python, pandas, folium

I am using folium to create a map and plot latitude and longitude points in a dataframe in that. This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import folium


lats =[]
lons =[]
texts=[]
for each in df1[0:len(df1)].iterrows():
     lat = each [1]['pickup_lat']
     lats.append(lat)
     lon = each [1]['pickup_lon']
     lons.append(lon)
     text= each[1]['vehicle_type']
     texts.append(text)
locations = list(zip(lats,lons))

map = folium.Map(location =[df1['pickup_lat'].mean(),df1['pickup_lon'].mean()],zoom_start =13)
folium.CircleMarker(location=locations ,radius=5,popup=texts).add_to(map)
```

This is the error I get:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-226-02aa653c3cd6> in <module>()
     16 
     17 map = folium.Map(location =[df1['pickup_lat'].mean(),df1['pickup_lon'].mean()],zoom_start =13)
---> 18 folium.CircleMarker(location=locations ,radius=5,popup=texts).add_to(map)

C:\Users\Harikrishna\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\folium\features.py in __init__(self, location, radius, color, weight, fill_color, fill_opacity, popup)
    765                  weight=2, fill_color='black', fill_opacity=0.6,
    766                  popup=None):
--> 767         super(CircleMarker, self).__init__(location, popup=popup)
    768         self._name = 'CircleMarker'
    769         self.radius = radius

C:\Users\Harikrishna\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\folium\map.py in __init__(self, location, popup, icon)
    612             self.add_child(Popup(popup))
    613         elif popup is not None:
--> 614             self.add_child(popup)
    615 
    616         self._template = Template(u"""

C:\Users\Harikrishna\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\branca\element.py in add_child(self, child, name, index)
     94         """Add a child."""
     95         if name is None:
---> 96             name = child.get_name()
     97         if index is None:
     98             self._children[name] = child

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_name'
```

But I am able to see the map if I just view the map. Just that I am unable to plot the latitude and longitude points in that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using a loop to add one marker at a time? In the folium documentation, they didn't mention you can add a list of markers at once.

Comment: for each in df1[0:len(df1)].iterrows():
    folium.CircleMarker(location=[each [1]['lat'], each [1]['long']], radius=0.8, color='#3186cc',
                    fill_color='#3186cc').add_to(map)